# Assistance needed to "snap" 3D model to 3D terrain mesh in XNA

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0

I'm trying to restrict the height of a model to the height of the mesh on which it's moving.  I have been looking into this issue for a short while and it seems like there are plenty of ways to solve the problem if I used a heightmap to generate the terrain, simply going back and checking the mesh's boundingsphere for collision with the vertex data stored during the mesh generation, but I like the idea of importing the mesh as a .x file.

I've been trying to wrap my head around creating a custom content processor to save the vertex data (edit:) **of the terrain** as a tag on the (edit:) **terrain** model, but it seems quite a deal more complex than I would have thought.  I've just gotten a hold of the triangle picking tutorial from Microsoft, and it seems like a possible solution, but is there another, simpler way?

I'm trying to move a mesh with no variation (a ball, for instance) over a potentially randomly generated mesh (terrain).  Any ideas, or should I just suffer through the learning curve imposed on me by the triangle picking example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer (which is what most do to generate their terrains) is to have your model contains in a bounding box, and let the model's reference point be the middle of the bottom of the bounding box. When you snap to terrain, you find the z value at the desired x,y point, and set that z value as the model's z value.

Now this will cause your terrain to sometimes look like this:[image]

But that's usually okay. It works for the snapping in most cases, then you manually tweak if you need to in the cases where it shows.

Comment: I should have been more delicate about my wording.  What the real question is, I suppose, is knowing the location of the bounding sphere for the model, how do I determine the height of the terrain mesh without having specifically stored vertex data for the terrain?  Is it even possible?

Comment: I would venture to say it's not possible. If you have the heightfield, you could find the three vertices you need, make your own triangle, and do the interpolation though. If you don't have the vertex data or the heightmap, though, there's nothing you can do.